# Completely left align number entries in a table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am using the `siunitx` package, along with the `booktabs` package, to make a table.

Here is my output:

[image: output]

**Table (a)** uses the tabular specification `llll` (i.e., no use of `siunitx`). **Table (a)** looks great, except that I want the decimal points in +0.2 and -0.4 to be lined up.

To do that, in **Table (b)**, I used the tabular specification `lSSS` and used `\sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}`. Now the decimal points are aligned, but I would like the numbers in the last two columns to be fully left aligned (flush with the `k_{\theta}`'s), since they are all positive. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,subcaption}
\DeclareSIUnit{\calorie}{cal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      \toprule
      & {$q$ (\si{\elementarycharge})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\calorie\per\mole})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\joule\per\mole})}\\
      \midrule
      compound A & +0.2 & 0.066 & 0.276144\\
      compound B & -0.4 & 0.14 & 0.585760\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

  \vspace*{16pt}

  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \caption{}
    \sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}
    \begin{tabular}{lSSS}
      \toprule
      & {$q$ (\si{\elementarycharge})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\calorie\per\mole})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\joule\per\mole})}\\
      \midrule
      compound A & +0.2 & 0.066 & 0.276144\\
      compound B & -0.4 & 0.14 & 0.585760\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of `table-number-alignment` in combination with the appropriate `table-format`, you can achieve the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\DeclareSIUnit{\calorie}{cal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l
                    S[table-format=-1.1,table-number-alignment=left]
                    S[table-format=1.3,table-number-alignment=left]
                    S[table-format=1.6,table-number-alignment=left]}
      \toprule
      & {$q$ (\si{\elementarycharge})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\calorie\per\mole})} & {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\joule\per\mole})}\\
      \midrule
      compound A & +0.2 & 0.066 & 0.276144\\
      compound B & -0.4 & 0.14 & 0.585760\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, however, I wonder, why I cant repeat result, if I move common option `table-number-alignment=left` in `\sisetup` for example after `\begin{table}` or into preamble? In this case the numbers are centered in column :-(

Comment: Even more interesting is, that the following specifications of table format wirks: `\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format= 1.6,table-number-alignment=left}
   \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=-1.1] S S}`. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Zarko: moving `table-number-alignment=left` into a `\sisetup` does not work since the use of `\table-format` overwrites the `table-number-alignment` to its default centered alignment, thus I had so specify the alignment for each column individually. (See also p.48 of the `siunitx` documentation.) Regarding your second comment: This suggestion only seems to work since column header and entries are almost equally wide, thus left aligned and centered almost look identical. If you add some caracters to the column header, you can see that this header is in fact again horizontally centered.

Answer (score 2):

You *need* to specify the format of numbers in each column; the simple `S` specification applies a default that's not suitable for your case.

On the other hand, the fact that the numbers are positive doesn't seem to have something to do with alignment.

I'd split the header into two rows, one for the symbols and one for the units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\DeclareSIUnit{\calorie}{cal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 l
 S[table-format=-1.1,retain-explicit-plus,table-number-alignment=left]
 S[table-format=1.3,table-number-alignment=left]
 S[table-format=1.6,table-number-alignment=left]
 @{}
}
\toprule
& {$q$ (\si{\elementarycharge})}
& {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\calorie\per\mole})}
& {$k_{\theta}$ (\si{\kilo\joule\per\mole})} \\
\midrule
compound A & +0.2 & 0.066 & 0.276144\\
compound B & -0.4 & 0.14 & 0.585760\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 l
 S[table-format=-1.1,retain-explicit-plus]
 S[table-format=1.3]
 S[table-format=1.6]
 @{}
}
\toprule
& {$q$}
& {$k_{\theta}$}
& {$k_{\theta}$} \\
& {(\si{\elementarycharge})}
& {(\si{\kilo\calorie\per\mole})}
& {(\si{\kilo\joule\per\mole})} \\
\midrule
compound A & +0.2 & 0.066 & 0.276144\\
compound B & -0.4 & 0.14 & 0.585760\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second sample, the big white space has disappeared.